# Difference between non-existent limits and divergent limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I was recently thinking about limits and how sometimes my prof says a limit is ''non-existent'' and other times he says that it is ''divergent''. I did some research and by the definition of the existence of a limit it must hold that both the limits from the negative and positive direction towards x are equal. This would imply that the limit exists.

If I now plot $$ \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \tan(x) $$ and look it up on Wolfram Alpha it says that the limit is exists and is ''divergent'' although $$ \lim_{{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}} \tan(x) $$ is not equal to $$ \lim_{{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}} \tan(x) $$

I now wonder if you only say a limit ''does not exist'' if you really have a function that is not defined for some values, i. e. $$ \ln(x) $$ for some x<0 or if you also say a limit does not exist if it diverges.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Anything that says $\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan(x)$ exists is just wrong. If Wolfram Alpha says that, please post a reference link.

Comment: Related [Limit of sequence exists but might be infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2907164/505767)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest idea is that "divergent" just means "not convergent". That raises the question "what does convergent mean?" The subtlety is whether we allow $\infty$ to be an accepted limit value, e.g., do we say $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x^2$ converges to $\infty$?

At the level of a calculus course, it's best to consider "convergent" to mean "has a finite limit from both directions" at the indicated limit point. So "divergent" means "does *not* have a finite common limit from both directions." I would not agree with Wolfram Alpha that $\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \tan x$ exists: as soon as a limit from one side or the other is $\pm\infty$, the function is not convergent there.

Keep in mind that "not convergent" doesn't have to mean $\infty$ is involved. Look at the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ as $x \to 0$ and you'll understand why $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(1/x)$ diverges (that is, $\sin(1/x)$ is not convergent as $x \to 0$) even though $\sin(1/x)$ is in $[-1,1]$ for all nonzero $x$.

Comment: The example really hit it home. I understand. Non-Convergence does not imply infinities to be involved, however, divergence implies inifinities involved. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TheDarkPingdom "divergence" does not imply infinities are involved. For example it is perfectly correct to say that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^{+}}\sin(1/x)$ diverges.

Comment: Exactly: the word "diverge" just means "does not converge".